# Select lines of a matrix with conditions

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix called a=

```
 lab col1 col2 col3
one    1    4    7
two    2    5    8
three  3    6    9
```

and i want to select only the lines that have the "lab"="one" and "two".

In fact my matrix is way bigger and i want to select a lot of different value from the column "lab".
I tried to do a vector

```
selected.lines=c("one","two")
a=a[a$lab==selected.lines,]
```

but it doesn't work, i guess because R tries to select the lines from the column "lab" that have a value equals to "one" AND "two"?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use `%in%` when the number of elements to compare are greater than 1 as `==` does a recycling  with the elements in 'selected.lines' i.e. the first elements in 'lab' are compared with the elements in 'selected.lines', then the third element in 'lab' is compared with the first element in 'selected.lines' and so on it till the end of the 'lab' column .  Also, with `matrix`, we use `[` for subsetting instead of `$`

```
a[a[,"lab"] %in% selected.lines,]
```